# Trying to view decision tree in my notebook

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, graphviz

I am trying to scale my decision tree to fit notebook but it appears not to scale properly. I have to keep scrolling for a better view. Can I please have some help on how to fix this. Attach is a pic of how it looks like.

```
from graphviz import Source
from sklearn import tree

from IPython.display import SVG
graph = Source( tree.export_graphviz(dt_classifier, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns))
SVG(graph.pipe(format='svg'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's not relevant any more, since this question has been open for about six months now. However, I just stumbled into it, as apparently 83 other readers, and I just crafted my way around this. The easy way is to use the pydot package (`pip install pydot`), and then add the default size. I have also been using `%matplotlib inline` so that it displays nicely within the notebook but without using the svg module. With your example:

```
%matplotlib inline

from graphviz import Source
from sklearn import tree
import pydot

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(dt_classifier, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns))
pdot = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
# Access element [0] because graph_from_dot_data actually returns a list of DOT elements.
pdot[0].set_graph_defaults(size = "\"15,15\"")
graph = Source(pdot[0].to_string())
graph
```

I also added `rotate=True` to `export_graphviz` so that it displays in horizontal style, the root of the tree is directly visible, and is easier to follow. Of course, you can play around with `size` so as to reach something that is acceptable for you.

[image: sample use of pydot for resizing graphviz data in Jupyter notebook]